# to find a  function with a property

Tags: real-analysis

We need to Find a non constant map $f:\mathbb{C}^3\to \mathbb{C}$ such that for any three distinct complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3$ and any automorphism $\phi$  of $\mathbb{C}$, we have
$f(z_1,z_2,z_3)= f(\phi(z_1),\phi(z_2),\phi(z_3))$

Thank you for help and discussion.

Comment: Whoops, I understand now that the analytic sense of automorphism (holomorphic bijection) is meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $z_i$s are all distinct, take

$f(z_1,z_2,z_3) = \frac{z_1-z_2}{z_3-z_2}$

This is the cross-ratio. It can take any complex value except for $0$ and $1$. It is clearly invariant. You can get many other functions by composing this with some function from $\mathbb C - \{0,1\}$ to $\mathbb C$. Indeed, these functions are all the possible functions, since if two triples have the same cross-ratio, they are the same up to an automorphism.